# Email File Replication

Tags: windows, email, replication

Do you have any recommendation for how to do file replication via Email? I would prefer an application that can run as a windows service and has a nice gui.

The remote location does not have a continuos internet connection which makes email the perfect solution if I only can find a nice application that supports replication by email.

I have looked at http://www.any-file-backup.com and it looks very promising feature wise but it does unfortunately not work... and there are no hits on google so perhaps no-one is using it (yet?).

**Edit:** Sometimes the only available communication is by satellite. A user sets up a connection and it will be available untill all emails are sent - then the connections is automatically taken down. That is why I'm not sure how I would solve this with another solution than email?

Comment: If you provide more details about your systema and setup, it may be easier to discern not to initiate your sat connection.

Answer (score 1):

I can honestly say that doing it by email is the wrong way.

[rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/), [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), [XCopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true), or [RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx) will all solve the problem of file synchronization.  Set up a scheduled task to do a true-up sync periodically and move on with life.

Even DFS is a better option if you're on the same domain...

Comment: Maybe you are right but I think maybe I should add some details before I move on with life. I will edit the question.

Comment: @sepang: If you look closely at the details regarding any-file-backup you'll see that email is not one of the transport mechanisms for file replication in that product. I'm with gWaldo on this and furthermore I've never heard of file replication via email and can't imagine how it might work, although I can imagine that it wouldn't work very well.

Comment: I understand it might not be the ideal solution. But I have downloaded any-file-backup and configured it to use email so I don't know what you mean by "look closely". you configure two separate tasks for send/receive. I can for sure imagine it working very well since email is pretty reliable. Not the ideal solution in most cases but still it could work very well. I have seen this kind of solution as part of bigger commercial systems for around-the-world-travelling ships. What I haven't found is a nice stand alone program I can purchase.

Comment: OK, I didn't see anything on their web site that stated it used email as the transport for file replication, I must have missed that.